# Is it right that other pages are also re-rendered when using Context Api?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I know that with Context Api, all the subcomponents under the provider are re-rendered when the context state is changed.

What I want to know is if only the components on the current screen are being re-rendered or if the whole components (including the page) under the provider are being re-rendered even if it is not shown on the screen.

The code Below is some of my Nextjs code. I want to add a common component to the provider, and I'm going to pass a `setState` on each page that allows changing the props of a common component.

When each page is mounted, the props of the common components will also change.
At this time, not only the current page is re-rendered, but all other pages are also re-rendered?

Then I think it's too inefficient, is there a way to optimize it?

```
// MyProvider
export const MyProvider = ({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) => {
    const [title, setTitle] = useState('');

    return (
        <MyContext.Provider
            value={{
                title,
                setTitle
            }}
        >
                    <CommonComponent title={title} />
            {children}
        </MyContext.Provider>
    );
};

// _app.tsx
…
return (
    <MyProvider>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
    </MyProvider>
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one page rendered at a time. For example, for the below `_app.js`, the Next.js team [says the following](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app):

> The `Component` prop is the active page, so whenever you navigate between routes, `Component` will change to the new `page`. Therefore, any props you send to `Component` will be received by the `page`.

```
export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}
```

And since you are passing a `children` to `MyProvider`, when your context changes, only the components of the **current page** that are directly consuming it re-render.